# Why is $\sum_{i<j}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i > \alpha, X_j > \alpha] \leq n \sum_{j=2}^n \mathbb{P}[X_1 > \alpha, X_j > \alpha]$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, inequality, stationary-processes

Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of stationary random variables. Why is the inequality
$$
\sum_{i < j}^{n} \mathbb{P}[X_i > \alpha, X_{j} > \alpha]
\leq n \sum_{j=2}^{n} \mathbb{P}[X_{1} > \alpha, X_{j} > \alpha]
$$
correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: write LHS as $\sum_i \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} P\{X_1 >\alpha, X_{j-i+1} >\alpha \}$ where I have used the fact that $(X_i,X_j)$ has the same joint distribution as $(X_1,X_{(j-i+1)})$. Now just interchange the sums on the left side and you will be able to get the stated inequality.

Comment: Interchanging the sum yields $\sum_{j = 2}^{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1} \mathbb{P}[X_1 > \alpha, X_{j-i+1} > \alpha]$, but how can I change $X_{j-i+1}$ to $X_{j}$?

Comment: Before you interchange the sums make the change of variable $k=j-i+1$; note that $k$ varies from 2 to $n-i+1$.

Comment: Then I obtain $\sum_{j = 2}^{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n-j+1} \mathbb{P}[X_1 > \alpha, X_{j} > \alpha]$.

Comment: @user893458 Since the probability does not depend on $i$ the inside sum is just $n-j+1$ which is $\leq n$.